# Android in app purchase without Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I want to create Android game with in app coin purchase but I do not want to use Google Play (or Amazon) in app billing. I want to publish it to slideme.org but cannot find good alternative other than PayPal. Is there any good alternative?